# Assembly - where am I going wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following program and arguments:

```
args: 0xbda42100,0xb98dd6a5,0xecded223

.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32

.global test

test:
push    ebp
mov     ebp,esp
mov eax,0xbc
xor al,al
mov ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0x9]   00000000 00000000 10100100 00000000 :simple move
sal ax,0x10                 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 :overflows so zeroes out
sub al,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xc]   00000000 00000000 00000000 01011010 :underflows so = 255 - val
add ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xd]   00000000 00000000 11010110 01011010 :simple mov
xor ax,WORD PTR [ebp+0x10]  00000000 00000000 01100001 10011000 :simple xor
```

I tried to trace the eax register in real time but somehow it's wrong. Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: The first `mov ah,` will store the 8 bits into b8-b15, not b0-b7 (that's aliased by `AL`). The other comments look reasonable, but I didn't check against the "args" values, because I'm not sure where the `ebp` points, maybe provide better example what you are seeing in the `eax` when stepping over instructions in debugger.

Comment: thanks, edited. I only have this to work with, no compiled program. I assume that the stack grows downward i.e. the address of arg 1 will be lower than the address of arg 3. So I assume arg1 is in epb + 8, arg2 in ebp +12 and arg3 in ebp + 16

Comment: sub will do 0-<value>, not 255. the opcodes are x86, so do you have in mind endianess? what API is this, will the args be pushed left to right, or right to left ? is BP saved in the stack-frame (for this will move the params even further) ?

Comment: the "args" doesn't mean anything in generic "assembly", you should specify your CPU and OS target, like it seems likely you are targeting "x86" CPU, in 32 bit mode, probably under linux or windows. That may give some hint, how exactly the "args" vs "ebp" is used, I'm personally not sure how the args are stored in memory. If you have the target platform, the code is so short, that it should be easy to write your own binary resembling this case, and debug over it. Debugging real code on machine will save you lot of time, when you cross-check against instruction reference guide = best learn XP.

Comment: so [edit] your question tags and text to add the details... mind you, each platform may implement these differently, it's even possible you will find two OS platforms on the same CPU in the same mode (x86-32), which will provide "args" in different way. "assembly" is not like some standardized-reference-language, it's just name for anything what's CPU related, and always platform specific.

Comment: the only info I have is that it is intel syntax, nothing more, this makes it challenging. The programm is called as new(args) i.e. new(0xbda42100,0xb98dd6a5,0xecded223) .

Comment: you assume `mov ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0x9]` leads to AH=0x94, what makes you think so? there is not a single 0x94 in the arguments. For what I see, it could be d2, d6 or 21 ... depending on push order and stack frame size. Educated guess: I assume it's 8, and EBP has been pushed too, to save it. otherwise the function would clobber it. If I would have to guess, I'd say it's 0xD2 ( 11010010 )

Comment: Why are you assuming the upper 16 bits of EAX are zero on function entry?  (It sounds like you have a function, not a whole program.  And presumably some prologue that sets up EBP as a stack frame?)  Wrong how? What values do you actually see in EAX?

Comment: Tried to add some clarification. @Tommylee2k how do you get to that conclusion? My assumption was that stack grows downward so ebp + 0x9 would be 21?

Comment: how do you get AH = 10100100b then?

Comment: My bad, it would be 0xA4 so 10100100